# Reducing query count on unique comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, join

I have a simple Events app which people can comment on and I have the ability to get the events a single user has commented on. Which would be unique.

I'm looking for a way I could possible put this into a Scope or just written better. Any tips would be greatly appreciated as right now it runs a new query obviously to do the `Event.find`

The code below is a mashup of some code I had written last week and then found some alternate ways of doing it but I think this could be improved, like the `events = []` - Surely that can be assigned when you append the Events.

```
def commented_on
    events = []
    self.comments.each do |c|
        p c
        events << Event.find(c.event_id)
    end

    # Return only unique Events
    p events.uniq
  end
```

Comment: Show us your models and their associations.

Comment: you can try events = Event.find(self.comments.select('event_id))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
events = Event.where(id: comments.map(&:event_id))
```

Comment: Thanks for this. This worked better for me but I changed it to. `Event.where(id: comments.map(&:event_id).uniq)`

Answer (score 2):

You should go from Events model here.
Something like that should work:

```
Event.join(:comments => :user).where("users.id" => self.id).uniq
```

Comment: Did you delete your previous answer and then repost?